# package.json dependencies exact version not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, npm-install, package.json

This is an excerpt from my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    [...]
}
```

According to the [package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) ("must match version **exactly**") it should get jQuery with version 2.2.3 when you do `npm install`.

So I was surprised when I found that in my `node_modules/jquery/dist` folder there is a `jquery.js` file which says: **jQuery JavaScript Library v3.0.0** (Which, of course, broke some of my code)

What happened here? Is this a bug? Is this intended behaviour because some other dependency has a jQuery@3.0.0 sub-dependency?
Same occurs when I put the caret in front of the version number (`"jquery": "^2.2.3"`). Could not find anything about this in the docs, on SO or on google, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, which makes npm ignore all changes to your `package.json` dependencies (devDependencies are not affected) and has a hardcoded jquery@3.0.0 version?

Delete that file and run `npm install` again.

If you need to, run `npm shrinkwrap` again afterwards to re-create the shrinkwrap file with the new version numbers.

See documentation here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap